# How do I enable logging of detailed information about garbage collection through the command line?

Tags: java, command-line, garbage-collection

I need to log info about GC through Java. How is it done and what exactly is the command to be used.

Thank you

Comment: how detailed exactly do you need? and which collector? Hotspot has many options influencing GC log verbosity and some are collector-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For details regarding GC calls you can enable it by passing these arguements to the command line

```
-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
```

Sample output logs will look something like below

```
2015-05-26T14:45:37.987-0200: 151.126: [GC (Allocation Failure) 151.126: [DefNew: 629119K->69888K(629120K), 0.0584157 secs] 1619346K->1273247K(2027264K), 0.0585007 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs]
2015-05-26T14:45:59.690-0200: 172.829: [GC (Allocation Failure) 172.829: [DefNew: 629120K->629120K(629120K), 0.0000372 secs]172.829: [Tenured: 1203359K->755802K(1398144K), 0.1855567 secs] 1832479K->755802K(2027264K), [Metaspace: 6741K->6741K(1056768K)], 0.1856954 secs] [Times: user=0.18 sys=0.00, real=0.18 secs]
```

To understand the above logs, take

1. `2015-05-26T14:45:37.987-0200` – Time when the GC event started.
2. `151.126` – Time when the GC event started, relative to the JVM startup time. Measured in seconds.
3. `GC` – Flag to distinguish between Minor & Full GC. This time it is indicating that this was a Minor GC.
4. `Allocation Failure` – Cause of the collection. In this case, the GC is triggered due to a data structure not fitting into any region in Young Generation.
5. `DefNew` – Name of the garbage collector used. This cryptic name stands for the single-threaded mark-copy stop-the-world garbage collector used to clean Young generation.
6. `629119K->69888K` – Usage of Young generation before and after collection.
7. `(629120K)` – Total size of the Young generation.
8. `1619346K->1273247K` – Total used heap before and after collection.
9. `(2027264K)` – Total available heap.
10. `0.0585007 secs` – Duration of the GC event in seconds.
11. `[Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs]` – Duration of the GC event, measured in different categories:

    - user – Total CPU time that was consumed by Garbage Collector threads during this collection
    - sys – Time spent in OS calls or waiting for system event
    - real – Clock time for which your application was stopped. As Serial Garbage Collector always uses just a single thread, real time is thus equal to the sum of user and system times.

Comment: Thank you, this gave me a detailed description!

Answer (score 2):

For a detailed information you need to pass all the arguments that I will list below. These options make Java to log garbage collector activities into specified file. All records will be prepended with human readable date and time. Meanwhile you should avoid using `-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps` as it will prepend record with useless timestamp since the moment Java application start. Read more about GC arguments [here](http://blog.sokolenko.me/2014/11/javavm-options-production.html) and [here](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/01/useful-jvm-flags-part-8-gc-logging/).

```
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps //adding DateStamps to log
-verbose:gc  //activates the a “simple” GC logging 
-XX:+PrintGCDetails //we activate the “detailed” GC logging mode
```

Sometimes it is interesting to know how long your application
runs between garbage collections. That can be calculated from the
GC logs but a convenient way to see that information is through
the the output that the next two flags produce. [Read more](https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/the-unspoken-application-times).

```
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime 
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime
```

**Enable log rotating**. It's important. The reasons is whenever the application is restarted, old GC log file will be over-ridden by the new GC log file as the file path is same (i.e. /home/GCEASY/gc.log). [Read more about GC log rotating](https://blog.gceasy.io/2016/11/15/rotating-gc-log-files/).

Also, GC log files rotation makes analysis of garbage collection problems easier, also it guaranties that disk is protected from space overconsumption.

```
-XX:GCLogFileSize=2M //default will be set to 512K
-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation //must be used with -Xloggc:<filename>
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 //must be >=1, default is one
```

And the file to write log into:

```
-Xloggc:$LOG_DIR/gc.log
```

Pass all of those in one line like:

```
XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:$LOG_DIR/gc.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable it with `-XX:+PrintGC` or `-verbose:gc`. For full details see https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/01/useful-jvm-flags-part-8-gc-logging/

Answer (score 0):

As stated in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

- -XX:-PrintGC Print messages at garbage collection. Manageable.
- -XX:-PrintGCDetails  Print more details at garbage collection. Manageable. (Introduced in 1.4.0.)
- -XX:-PrintGCTimeStamps   Print timestamps at garbage collection. Manageable (Introduced in 1.4.0.)